# opening an already opened form without losing data

Tags: c#

i have two forms form1 and form2. form 2 is opened using form1's next button.you can also go back to form1 from form2. i need to open a new form2 only for the first time and afterwards i just need form2 to load with all the previously entered data without any data loss when the next button is clicked.

//form1
//i need to check if form2 is already opened and then if it is not this should happen. If it is already opened i need to load that form without creating  new one

```
private void nextBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2 = new Form3();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retain the previously created form and re-use it.

```
if (form2 == null) {
    form2 = new Form3();
}

form2.ShowDialog();
```

Usually the individual forms in the wizard or sequence would be managed by a container such as a `TabControl`.